# How do you make a dropdown links in a responsive menu display beyond the height of the menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS responsive main menu which I created using code from a couple of different examples. Thus far I have discovered one major flaw. In responsive mode dropdown menu items that extend beyond the normal height of the menu disappear. You can see a demo at:

[Main Menu Demo](https://dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/nav-demo/menu.html)

It seems to be related to overflow. I tried various versions of overflow:hidden and overflow:visible with small/large device sizes with no success. Maybe that's not really the problem, just what I see. Here is the code from that part of the CSS:

```
/* overflow hack somewhere around here - add height to toplevel to get menu to display all dropdown in mobile */
.header ul.toplevel {
  overflow: hidden; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header ul.toplevel {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .header ul.toplevel {
    height: 360px; /* the hack */ 
  }
  .header ul.dropdown {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header ul {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown ul {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

/* end overflow hack area */
```

Viewing the source you can see both CSS and plain HTML. There is no javascript. The tmp fix of setting a height to the .header ul.toplevel on small devices is awkward at best. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try add this

```
ul.dropdown .dropdown-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: if I understand you have problem with Second Dropdown?

Comment: The problem was with all dropdowns on small devices. With the first dropdown I should have added a couple items to it to visualize it. Anyway, I placed the code which you provided in the media query for small devices and it worked. Thanks much.